# Integral equation solution: $y(x) = 1 + \lambda\int\limits_0^2\cos(x-t) y(t) \mathrm{d}t$

Tags: integration, integral-equations

Integral equation

$$y(x) = 1 + \lambda\int\limits_0^2\cos(x-t) y(t) \mathrm{d}t$$ has:

> 1. a unique solution for $\lambda \neq \frac{4}{\pi +2}$;
> 2. a unique solution for $\lambda \neq \frac{4}{\pi -2}$;
> 3. no solution for $\lambda \neq \frac{4}{\pi +2}$, but the corresponding homogeneous equation has a non-trivial solution; or
> 4. no solution for $\lambda \neq \frac{4}{\pi -2}$, but the corresponding homogeneous equation has a non-trivial solution.

I am stuck on this problem. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: If it is a question of some Indian Entrance Examination please add the source (Exam. name, year)in the title of this question. It will be helpful to other students using this site.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use $$\cos(x-t)=\cos x\cos t+\sin x\sin t$$ and derive twice. After that you get:
$$y^{\prime\prime}(x)=-(\lambda\int_{0}^2\cos(x-t)y(t)dt)$$
and so
$$y^{\prime\prime}+y-1=0$$
The corresponding homogenous equation is
$$y^{\prime\prime}+y=0$$
The solution is $y=a\cos x+b\sin x+1$. We just have to subsititute it back in the original equation. Then,
$$a\cos x+b\sin x+1=1+\lambda \int_{0}^2\cos(x-t)(a\cos t+b\sin t+1)dt$$
and so
$$a\cos x+b\sin x=\lambda \cos x\int_{0}^2\cos t(a\cos t+b\sin t+1)dt+\\\lambda \sin x\int_{0}^2\sin t(a\cos t+b\sin t+1)dt$$
Therefore, we have the system of equations:
\begin{gather}a=\lambda \int_{0}^2\cos t(a\cos t+b\sin t+1)dt\\
b=\lambda \int_{0}^2\sin t(a\cos t+b\sin t+1)dt\end{gather}

Comment: $a\doteq \lambda \sin t \int_0^2 (a\cos t \sin t + b\sin^2 t +  \sin t) dt $.it getting hard

Comment: its getting hard ,i have to then solve for homogeneous also,is there any shortcut........

Comment: @pankaj I don't know any shortcut you can take other than computing the integrals, that are by the way easier than you think. Look at Mhenni's answer for more info

Comment: sir tell me what I do after finding a,b

Comment: non trivial means what sir...........

Comment: @pankaj You will find $a,b$ with respect to $\lambda$. Now a trivial solution to the homogenous is $y=0$. The problems asks for other solutions.

Comment: OKK its somewhat lengthy..........

Answer (score 2):

Related technique: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349133/solution-of-an-integral-equation-phix-int1-0-xtxt-phit-dt-x-0), [(II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405786/fredholm-equations). The integral equation you have is a "Fredholm equation of the 2nd kind with seperable kernel". There are standard techniques to solve this type of equations. See [here, page 20](http://www.orcca.on.ca/TechReports/TechReports/2008/TR-08-03.pdf) for the method and a worked example how to find such $\lambda$.

Comment: its  hard ,i have to  solve for homogeneous and non homogeneous also,is there any shortcut.....

Comment: @pankaj: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: @pankaj: From what course has this problem come from?

Comment: This is indeed a *Fredholm equation of the 2nd kind with seperable kernel*... but the fact that is irrelevant. Please try not to send the OP on deadends.