# Solution of an integral equation $\phi(x)+\int^1_0 xt(x+t)\phi(t)\,dt=x $ , $0 \le x \le 1 $

Tags: integral-equations

Solve the following integral equation:

$\phi(x)+\displaystyle \int^1_0 xt(x+t)\phi(t)\,dt=x $ , $0 \le x \le 1 $

---

I need to solve the integral equation above. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What method do you want to use?

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $$\phi(x)+x^2 \displaystyle \int_0^1t\phi(t)dt+x\int_0^1t^2\phi(t)=x$$ 
i.e. $$\tag{1}\phi(x)=c_1x^2+c_2x $$

Where $c_1 = - \displaystyle \int_0^1t\phi(t)dt \ \ $ and $\ \ c_2=1- \displaystyle \int_0^1t^2\phi(t)dt$

Put $\phi(t)$ from $(1)$ in these integrals and calculate  $c_1 \ , \ c_2$ from two equations you get

(two-equations  two variables).

Comment: You can use the `\tag{}` command to tag equations. Apparently, it doesn't accept \spadesuit as an input, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

Related problems: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401901/solve-integral-equation-of-second-kind-using-fredholm-method/414314#414314). Here is a detailed solution that maybe someone benefits from it. Rearranging the equation as
$$ \phi(x)= x- \displaystyle \int^1_0 xt(x+t)\phi(t)\,dt \longrightarrow (1). $$

$$  \phi(x) = x - x^2\int_{0}^{1}t\phi(t)\,dt - x \int_{0}^{1}t^2\phi(t) \,dt $$

$$ \implies  \phi(x) = x - x^2 c_1 - x c_2 \longrightarrow (2).$$

Now, just subs back in the integral equation $(1)$ and compare the coefficients of $x's$, you will get a system of 2 equations in $c_1$ and $c_2$

$$ \frac{5}{4}c_{1}+\frac{1}{3}c_{2}= \frac{1}{3} $$

$$ \frac{1}{5}c_{1}+\frac{5}{4}c_{2}= \frac{1}{4}. $$

Solving the above system gives

$$ \left\{ c_{{1}}={\frac {80}{359}},c_{{2}}={\frac {59}{359}} \right\}.  $$

Subs back in $(2)$ yields the solution

$$ \phi \left( x \right) ={\frac {300}{359}}\,x-{\frac {80}{359}}\,{x}^{2
},$$

which can be checked by plugging back in $(1)$.

Comment: @moderators: This down vote is a misleading.

Comment: @Downvoters: What's the down vote for? This is the second one.

Comment: This solution is correct, +1. I don't know why it was downvoted. But does @moderators really notify the moderators? And do they really have to be notified in such a case? What could they  do anyway?

Comment: @julien: It is really a misleading down vote. I worked out the problem in details so it will be like a reference for people.

Comment: Also, note that instead of substituting back and comparing coefficients, you can do $c_1=\int t\phi(t)=(1-c_2)\int t^2-c_1\int t^3$ and likewise for $c_2=\int t^2\phi(t)$.

Comment: @julien: You are right. Verifying the answer is a good exercise for the OP.

Comment: You understood that I upvoted, right? I even took the time to check the computations up to the system. Which is why I don't understand the downvotes either. But again, what do you expect the moderators to do about that?

Comment: @julien: We need to find a solution about these misleading down votes or those ones that happened by mistakes. However, whenever this happens, I usually put a comment under my answers and the post of the OP.

Comment: And what is the outcome of doing so? Has a moderator ever done anything about it? Are they notified by @moderators? What can they do anyway? I think you should ask yourself these questions first.

Comment: @julien: You are wright. One time, I found a comment says "why moderators have to be notified about that?"!!. So, I thought they should be notified.