# Integral eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, functional-analysis, integral-equations

I need to find the eigenvalues e eigenvectors of this integral.

a)
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}(\cos^2(x+y)+1/2)\phi (y)dy$$

b)- Solved thanks
$$\int_{0}^{1}(x^2y^2-2/45)\phi (y)dy$$

Comment: I tried to define the matrix to get the determinant and but I defined the a(x)'s and b(y)'s right from the beginning for sure

Comment: Why are these eigenvalues urgent? DO WE NEED TO GET THEM TO THE PRESIDENT?

Comment: Very funny you all.. If you're not here to help people you shouldn't be here at all!

Comment: It's not like this is a paid job for us. There are no matrices in this problem. You are looking at the vector space of continuous functions, not $\mathbb R^n$. The integrals define $T(\phi)$ for continuous functions $\phi$. You want to know for what $\lambda$ we find a non-zero function $\phi$ with $T(\phi) = \lambda\phi$. Presumably you have something in your textbook or class notes that deals with examples like this?

Comment: Not really.. Nothing like this just usual second kind integral equations...

Comment: Hint: Look at part b). When you do this integral (regardless of what $\phi(y)$ is) what sort of function of $x$ is your answer?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: People are giving you a hard time because when you post in all caps "URGENT HELP PLEASE" you are implying there is a time limit. This often reads as if you are taking a timed test, or possibly that you are very late in starting your homework. Otherwise, why "URGENT"? Also, ALL CAPS IS READ AS SHOUTING, WHICH IS CONSIDERED RUDE WHEN ASKING FOR HELP FROM STRANGERS.

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: Try some simple functions $\phi(y)$ and see what answers you get when you compute the integral. Four or five examples should be good. See if you can then guess what *form* $\phi(y)$ has to get in order for it to be an eigenfunction.

Comment: What is the course you are taking?

Answer (score 3):

First, let me try to rephrase part of the question in a way that is likely to be more palatable for most folks on math.SE:

**Edited question**

I would like to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1}(x^2y^2-2/45)\phi (y)dy$$

I tried to find a matrix so I could compute the determinant, but I'm not sure what matrix I should use.

**Discussion on the edit**

Note that we are at least indicating *some* attempt to indicate our thoughts.  Even if this is minimal, it demonstrates to folks who are donating there time to adress your question where you are.  Also, *never* use URGENT in all caps in your title; I promise that it won't go over well.

Finally, it's generally considered polite to upvote an answer that gives reasonable help and to accept the best answer whenever appropriate.  I notice that you have 14 questions with only one accept.

**A partial answer**

At any rate, after that, someone is likely to politely explain that this is not a problem involving matrices.  Rather, you are looking for a function $\phi(x)$ and a non-zero, real number $\lambda$ such that

$$\int_{0}^{1}(x^2y^2-2/45)\phi (y)dy = \lambda \phi(x).$$

My recommendation is that you guess and refine.  If you let $\phi(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and compute the integral, you should find that

$$\int_{0}^{1}(x^2y^2-2/45)(ay^2+by+c)dy = -\frac{2 a}{135}-\frac{2 c}{45}-\frac{2 b \
x}{45}+\left(\frac{a}{5}+\frac{c}{3}\right) x^2+\frac{b x^3}{3}.$$

From there, the question is simply, can you find $a$, $b$, and $c$ to make this work?  It's reasonably clear that $b=0$, right?  I bet you can make some progress from here.

*One more hint*: My solutions for $\lambda$ have a 45 in the denominator. I also solved for $a$ in terms of $c$, which is to be expected in an eigenvalue problem.

Good luck!

Comment: I got $$c=-a/5$$ and  then a=8/9 and c=-8/135 And $$\ϕ=15x^2-1$$. To $c= -2a/3$$ I got a=9/2 and c=3 and $$ϕ=3x^2-2$$. Is it right????     I can't calculate the λ.. Can you help me out????

Comment: @Amccds You could certainly [use WolframAlpha](http://goo.gl/cPPHc).

Comment: Is these values I calculate correct? How do I get the  lambda

Comment: B) is done thanks

Comment: I really need help in question a) I can't solve it... Can you help me out?????

Comment: @Amccds I recommend that you ask another question with a title that is something like "Final steps to find eigenfunctions associated with an integral operator". Clearly outline what you've done and where you're stuck. Someone will pick it up. Incidentally, did you click on the WolframAlpha link? It will tell you the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Related problem:[(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405786/fredholm-equations), [(II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408777/volterra-integral-equation-with-variable-boundaries/411355#411355). Here is a start and you have to work out the details. First, you need to find the eigen values $\lambda$ by solving the integral equations

$$ \phi(x) = \lambda\int_{0}^{2\pi}(\cos^2(x+y)+1/2)\phi (y)dy,$$

$$ \phi(x) = \lambda\int_{0}^{1}(x^2y^2-2/45)\phi (y)dy .$$

Now, both of the integral equations have separable kernels which the following [method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349133/solution-of-an-integral-equation-phix-int1-0-xtxt-phit-dt-x-0/393672#393672) can be used.

**Note:**

$$ \cos^2(x+y)=\frac{\cos(2x+2y)}{2}+\frac{1}{2} $$

$$ \cos(x+y)=\cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y). $$

**Added:** It seems your book adopting the convention

$$ \lambda \phi(x) = \int_{0}^{2\pi}(\cos^2(x+y)+1/2)\phi (y)dy.$$

Now, using the above hints, we have

$$ \lambda \phi(x) = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\frac{\cos(2x+2y)}{2} + 1/2 \right)\phi(y)dy$$

$$\implies \lambda \phi(x) = \cos(2x)\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\cos(2y)}{2}\phi(y)dy - \sin(2 x) \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\sin(2y)}{2}\phi(y)dy$$

$$ + \int_{0}^{2\pi}\phi(y) dy \longrightarrow (1).  $$

$$ \implies \lambda \phi(x) = \cos(2x) c_1 - \sin(2 x) c_2 + c_3  $$

$$ \implies \phi(x) = \frac{1}{\lambda}\cos(2x) c_1 - \frac{1}{\lambda}\sin(2 x) c_2 + \frac{1}{\lambda}c_3.  $$

Now, subs back in $(1)$ and simplify, you get

$$ \left( c_{{1}}-{\frac {c_{{1}}\pi }{\lambda}} \right) \cos \left( 2\,
x \right) + \left( -c_{{2}}-{\frac {c_{{2}}\pi }{\lambda}} \right) 
\sin \left( 2\,x \right) +c_{{3}}-2\,{\frac {c_{{3}}\pi }{\lambda}}=0.$$

Now, by equating the coefficients, we have $\lambda=2\pi,\pi $ and $-\pi$. However, $\lambda=2\pi$ will give the solution $\phi(x)=1$. You can check this solution by substituting in $(1)$.

Comment: I need help here. I don't know how to get the function inside the integral to make it work... Tried different approaches an nothing helped.. I'm talking about the coseno one...

Comment: @Amccds: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405786/fredholm-equations).

Comment: Ive tried a lot of expressions and expansions to replace the original $$cos^2(x+y)+1/2$$ and but could solve the problem... On the other side of the equation put $$\lambda(asin(2x)+bcos(2x))$$

Comment: Hello again. I got something already. This is what i did: $$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2\pi}((cos(2x)cos(2y)-sin(2x)sin(2y)+ \frac{1}{2}) +\frac{1}{2})\phi (y)dy= \lambda*a*cos(2x)+\lambda*b*sin(2x)$$ and then $$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2\pi}((cos(2x)cos(2y)-sin(2x)sin(2y)+ \frac{1}{2}) +\frac{1}{2})(a*cos(2y)+b*sin(2y))dy= \lambda*a*cos(2x)+\lambda*b*sin(2x)$$. The I solved the integrals and I got this I got the $$\frac{\pi}{2}b=\lambda*a$$. From this I got $$\lambda=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ and $$a=0$$ and $$\phi(x)=cos(2x)$$. I also got $$\lambda=\frac{-\pi}{2}$$ and $$b=0$$ and so $$\phi(x)=sin(2x)$$...

Comment: But in my book there is a another $$\lambda=2\pi$$ where $$\phi(x)=1$$, that I can't find and I don't know how to get. Can you please help me out with this one????