# Volterra integral equation with variable boundaries

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-equations

$$\phi (x)=x+\lambda \int_{a}^{x}(x-y)\phi (y)dy$$

I'm also Trying to solve this integral equation like she does
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404959/solving-an-integral-equation-with-a-separable-kernel/408757#408757
and I also have some doubts about it. What to do? It's the first time I'm solving something like this, I only learned the matrix and determinant method for usual equation integrals.  Can you explain how to solve this equation integrals? I searched the web but didn't get much anything to help me solve this. Thank a lot

Comment: The techniques for solving integral equations vary greatly based on the form they take. What is the one you are trying to solve?

Comment: Try differentiating w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: Yes I did like in the other link.but what I do next?

Comment: @Amccds: Are you taking a course in integral equations?

Answer (score 3):

Related problem: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140106/volterra-integral-equation-of-secong-type-solve-using-resolvent-kernel/425186#425186), [(II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404889/integral-eigenvectors-and-eigenvalues). You can use the method of successive approximation which can be summarized as

$$ \phi_{n} (x)=x+\lambda \int_{a}^{x}(x-y)\phi_{n-1} (y)dy,$$

where $\phi_0(x)$ can be any real valued function. For simplicity, you can choose $\phi_0(x)=0$, then start to find $\phi_1,\phi_2,\dots$. For instance,

$$ \phi_1(x)=x+\lambda \int_{a}^{x}(x-y)(0)dy = x.$$

$$ \phi_{2} (x)=x+\lambda \int_{a}^{x}(x-y)\phi_{1} (y)dy $$

$$ \phi_{2} (x)=x+\lambda \int_{a}^{x}(x-y)(y)dy = \dots.$$

If you can get a general formula for $\phi_n(x)$, then the solution $\phi(x)$ will be

$$ \phi(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \phi_n(x). $$

Off course this process will impose some conditions on $\lambda$.

**Another approach:** Here is another approach. Differentiating the integral equation, we get

$$ \phi (x)=x+\lambda \int_{a}^{x}(x-y)\phi (y)dy \implies \phi'(x)= 1+\lambda\int_{a}^{x}\phi(y) dy. $$

Differentiating again, we get the differential equation

$$ \phi''(x) = \lambda \phi(x). $$

Solving the ode subject to the initial conditions $\phi(a)=a$ and $\phi'(a)=1$ gives the desired solution

$$ \phi \left( x \right) = \frac{1}{2}\,{\frac { \left( \sqrt {\lambda}a+1
 \right) {{\rm e}^{\sqrt {\lambda}x}}}{{{\rm e}^{\sqrt {\lambda}a}}
\sqrt {\lambda}}}+\frac{1}{2}\,{\frac { \left( \sqrt {\lambda}a-1 \right) {
{\rm e}^{-\sqrt {\lambda}x}}}{{{\rm e}^{-\sqrt {\lambda}a}}\sqrt {
\lambda}}}.$$