# How to differentiate this equation involving an integral expression?

Tags: calculus, integral-equations

I want to differentiate the Volterra integral equation $\phi(t) + \int_0^t (t - \xi) \, \phi(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}{\xi} = \sin{2t}$.

Am I right in thinking that the integral can just be removed like so?

$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left( \phi(t) + \int_0^t (t - \xi) \, \phi(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}{\xi} = \sin{2t} \right)\\ = \phi'(t) + (t - \xi) \, \phi(\xi) = 2\cos{2t}$

And in general, how do you differentiate equations involving integral expressions? I haven't encountered equations of this nature before.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408777/volterra-integral-equation-with-variable-boundaries).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule is a related rule.

Answer (score 4):

I think you confused the limit of integration and its variable.

If we define $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
$$F(t)=\int_0^t(t-\xi)\phi(\xi)d\xi=t\int_0^t\phi(\xi)d\xi-\int_0^t\xi\phi(\xi)d\xi$$
Then deriving both sides using linearity, the product rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus we get
$$F'(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\left(t\int_0^t\phi(\xi)d\xi\right)-\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_0^t\xi\phi(\xi)d\xi\right)$$
$$F'(t)=1\int_0^t\phi(\xi)d\xi+t\phi(t)-t\phi(t)=\int_0^t\phi(\xi)d\xi$$

In general you should separate the "$t$"s and "$\xi$"s before differentiating