# solution of a volterra equation

Tags: calculus, integration, integral-equations

I have to find solution of followong volterra equation

$y(x)= x -  \int_{0}^{x}(x-t) y(t) dt$ with $y(0) = 0$.

My attempt:

I differentiated the above and got

$y^\prime = 1 -  \int_{0}^{x} y(t) dt  \tag 1$

Again differentiating I get

$y^{\prime \prime} = 0 -  y(x)$.   $~~~~~$Now we get its solution as :

$y = c_1 \cos x +c_2 \sin x$ and using the condition $y(0) = 0$ we get

$y = c_2 \sin x$. Now when we differentiate this $y$ and compare with equation (1) at $x = 0$,  we get $c_2 = 1$ and this gives $y = \sin x $ as the answer. Is my solution correct? Kindly rectify if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: looks good to me.

Comment: calculation looks fine, substituting the solution back into the original equation works out as well.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408777/volterra-integral-equation-with-variable-boundaries).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a way of verifying/deriving your solution starting from 
$$y^{\prime \prime} = -y \text{ and initial conditions }y(0) = 0, y^\prime(0) = 1.$$

$\begin{align}
  y(x)  & =  \int_0^x y^\prime(t)\ dt 
       =  \int_0^x y^\prime(t)d(t-x) \\
 & = y^\prime(t)(t-x)|_0^x - \int_0^x (t-x)y^{\prime \prime}(t) \ dt \\
 &= x y^\prime (0)+\int_0^x (t-x)y(t) dt \\
 &=x - \int_0^x(x-t)y(t)\  dt
\end{align}$