# Solving the simplified Volterra equation

Tags: laplace-transform, integral-equations

Just a quick question! I'm trying to solve a Volterra equation using the Laplace transform.

$$\ u(t) = t -  \int_{0}^{t} (t-s) u(s) ds $$

where kernel $\ k(t,s) = t-s $. 
I've the solution for this question but what happens if the kernel is simplified to $\ k(s) = s$ such that: 
$$\ u(t) = t -  \int_{0}^{t} s u(s) ds $$

In this case, $\ f(t)=t $ but $\ k(t) = 0$. Then the Laplace transform of k would be $\ L[k]=0 $? It doesn't feel right. What do you think?

Another question: 
I saw another Volterra question here: [solution of a volterra equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105147/solution-of-a-volterra-equation) 
but why did he differentiate the equation instead of using the Laplace transform method?

Thanks!!

Comment: You seem to have substituted $t=0$ only in one place, but you must replace all occurrences of $t$ in the first equation, which gives $u(0)=0$ as expected.

Comment: @hardmath, Hi there. Sorry, I edited the question. I meant to say that the kernel is simplified to $ s$ and no longer $ (t - s)$.

Comment: The notation is still difficult to follow, in part because you omitted "the Volterra equation" per se, so that the mentions of $f(t)$ and $k(t)$ are not grounded.

Comment: @hardmath oh, I'm sorry. So, how do I solve the 2nd equation?

Answer (score 1):

This is the OP's "second equation" that is to be solved (see Comments):

$$ \ u(t) = t -  \int_{0}^{t} s\; u(s)\; ds $$

A typical approach to solving such integral equations is by fixed point iteration.

That is, suppose we define $u_0(t) \equiv 0$.  Then for successive indexes we compute:

$$ u_{k+1}(t) = t - \int_0^t s\; u_k(s)\; ds $$

As a result we get these first few iterations:

$$ u_1(t) = t - 0 = t $$

$$ u_2(t) = t - \frac{t^3}{3} $$

$$ u_3(t) = t - \frac{t^3}{3} + \frac{t^5}{15} $$

$$ u_4(t) = t - \frac{t^3}{3} + \frac{t^5}{15} - \frac{t^7}{105} $$

Clearly (by induction) the limit of sequence $u_k$ is the power series:

$$ u(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{t^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!!} $$

I don't know right off what the "closed form" of this power series might be, but the Answers to the previous Question [Double factorial series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482211/double-factorial-series) suggest that it is related to an exponential integral.