# Solve the equation: $x(t)-3\int_0^1(s+t)x(s)ds=y(t)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Given $y\in L^2[0,1]$, Solve the equation:
$$x(t)-3\int_0^1(s+t)x(s)ds=y(t)$$

I have noticed that the equation is $(I-K)(x(t))=y(t)$, where $K(f(t))=\int_0^13(s+t)f(s)ds$ is a compact integral operator in $L^2[0,1]$, so Fredholm alternative is an idea.

I don't know how to continue with the homogeneous equation $(I-K)(x(t))=0$. How can I get a solution to the inhomogeneous equation?

Thanks!

Comment: If you look again at $K$, you may notice that $K(f)$ always has a very specific form.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349133/solution-of-an-integral-equation-phix-int1-0-xtxt-phit-dt-x-0) a technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{{\rm x}\pars{t} -3\int_{0}^{1}\pars{s + t}{\rm x}\pars{s}\,\dd s
     ={\rm y}\pars{t}}$

> \begin{align}
> \color{#66f}{\large{\rm x}\pars{t}}&=
> \color{#66f}{\large 3\mu + 3\nu t + {\rm y}\pars{t}}\,,\qquad
> \mu \equiv \int_{0}^{1}s{\rm x}\pars{s}\,\dd s\,,\quad
> \nu\equiv\int_{0}^{1}{\rm x}\pars{s}\,\dd s
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
\mu &=\int_{0}^{1}s\bracks{3\mu + 3\nu s + {\rm y}\pars{s}}\,\dd s
={3 \over 2}\,\mu + \nu + \phi\,,\qquad
\color{#66f}{\large\phi}\equiv
\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}s{\rm y}\pars{s}\,\dd s}
\\[3mm]
\nu &=\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{3\mu + 3\nu s + {\rm y}\pars{s}}\,\dd s
=3\mu + {3 \over 2}\,\nu + \varphi\,,\qquad
\color{#66f}{\large\varphi}\equiv\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{1}{\rm y}\pars{s}\,\dd s}
\end{align}

> $$
> \left.\begin{array}{rcrcl}
> -\,\half\,\mu & - & \nu & = & \phi
> \\
> -3\mu & - & \half\,\nu & = & \varphi
> \end{array}\right\rbrace\qquad\imp\qquad\color{#66f}{\large%
> \left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcr}
> \mu & = & {2 \over 11}\,\pars{\phi - 2\varphi}
> \\[2mm]
> \nu & = & -\,{2 \over 11}\,\pars{6\phi - \varphi}
> \end{array}\right.}
> $$