# Find spectrum of the operator and an explicit form for the solution

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $A: L^2[0,2\pi] \to L^2[0,2\pi]$ be defined by $Au=v$ if

$v(x)=\int^{2\pi}_{0} cos(x+t)u(t)dt$

(a) Find the point spectrum, eigenspace, residual spectrum, continuous spectrum, and spectrum

(b) Suppose $\lambda^{-1} \not\in \sigma(T)$ and $g \in L^2[a,b]$. Obtain an explicit form for the solution of $u=g+\lambda Au$ and write it in the form $u(x)=\phi(x)+\int^{2\pi}_{0}\Gamma(\lambda,x,t)\phi(t)dt$

Comment: So, What is the definition of point spectrum? Basically, You need to solve the integral equation $ Au=\lambda u $.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261496/integral-equation-solution-yx-1-lambda-int-limits-02-cosx-t-yt-ma) for the technique.