# Fredholm Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, integral-equations

I have the following problem to solve

$$\phi (x)=\lambda \int_{o}^{\pi }\cos(2x+y)\phi (y) dy+ \sin x$$

following the instructions from the [following link](http://www2.kau.se/yourshes/integrkomp.pdf) early to conclude that:

$$\phi (x)=\lambda \int_{o}^{\pi }\cos(2x+y)\phi (y) dy+\sin x$$ $$=\lambda \int_{o}^{\pi }\cos^2(x)\cos(y)-\sin^2(x)\cos(y)-2\sin(x)\cos(x)\sin(y)\phi (y) dy+ \sin x$$

then start to calculate $a_{11}, a_{12},a_{13},a_{21},a_{22},a_{23},a_{31},a_{32},a_{33}$, such that (these will be the elements of the matrix A):

$$a_{1}=\cos^2(x);a_{2}=-\sin^2(x) ;a _{3}=-2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$

$$b_{1}=\cos(y);b_{2}=\cos(y) ;b_{3}=\sin(y)$$

thus calculated:

$$a_{11}=\int_{o}^{\pi }b_{1}(y)a_{1}(y)dy$$

$$a_{12}=\int_{o}^{\pi }b_{1}(y)a_{2}(y)dy$$

$$a_{13}=\int_{o}^{\pi }b_{1}(y)a_{3}(y)dy$$

calculating and so on until all $a_{nm}$ with $n =1,2,3$ and $m=1,2,3$.

After calculations we obtain the matrix

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} &a_{12}  & a_{13}\\ 
a _{21}&a_{22}  & a_{23}\\ 
a_{31} &a_{32}  & a_{33} 
\end{bmatrix}$$

making: $\;(I-\lambda A)$,

and calculating the determinant originated by $\;(I-\lambda A)$, get all values ​​of $\lambda$.

The solutions they have there is only one $\lambda=3/2\sqrt{2}$ and $\lambda=-3/2\sqrt{2}$

But never get to that result. I appreciate any and all help. I do not even know if I was wrong in whole or in calculating the determinant of the matrix.

Comment: @OlindaFernandes: [A related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349133/solution-of-an-integral-equation-phix-int1-0-xtxt-phit-dt-x-0).

Answer (score 2):

[Related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349133/solution-of-an-integral-equation-phix-int1-0-xtxt-phit-dt-x-0). First note this, the solution is

$$  \phi \left( x \right) =\sin \left( x \right) +12\,{\frac {{\lambda}^{2
}\pi \,  \cos^2\left( x \right) }{8\,{\lambda}^{2}-9
}}-6\,{\frac {{\lambda}^{2}\pi }{8\,{\lambda}^{2}-9}}+9\,{\frac {\pi 
\,\lambda\,\sin \left( x \right) \cos \left( x \right) }{8\,{\lambda}^
{2}-9}}.$$

Now, you can see the singular values or the wanted $\lambda$ is given by

$$ 8\,\lambda^{2}-9 = 0  \implies \lambda = -\frac{3}{2\sqrt{2}},\,\frac{3}{2\sqrt{2}}.$$

**Added:** Here is a start

$$ \phi (x)=\lambda \int_{o}^{\pi }\cos(2x+y)\phi (y) dy+\sin x  $$

$$ \phi(x)  =  \sin(x) +\lambda \cos(2x)\int_{0}^{\pi }\cos(y)\phi (y) dy - \sin(2x) \int_{0}^{\pi }\sin(y)\phi (y) dy   $$

> $$  \phi(x)  =  \sin(x) +\lambda c_1\cos(2x) - \lambda c_2 \sin(2x). $$

Now, just follow the technique in the link and you should not have a problem.

Comment: how it came to this result?

Comment: @OlindaFernandes: Try to follow the technique in to link I referred you to, then start solving your problem. Just work out the problem step by step and you will get the answer.

Comment: @OlindaFernandes: You are welcome.

Comment: I'm so really thanks

Comment: @OlindaFernandes: You are very welcome.

Comment: thank you very much, I was trying to get to the first speech you gave me through the last you gave me, ie, through the expression of $\phi(x)=sin(x)+...-\lambda c_{2}sin(x)$ reach $\phi(x)=sin(x)+12...$

Comment: @OlindaFernandes; You are very welcome.