# Integral equation that's cant solve... Need a hand

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations, integral-equations

Help me solve this integral equation, I'm having some troubles... I need to use the Fredholm method for second kind integral equations.

$$\phi(x)= \sin(x)+ \lambda \int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(2x+y)\phi (y)dy$$

Thanks

Comment: duplicate question asked within the hour: [Fredholm equations](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405786/fredholm-equations)

Comment: Is $sen(x)$ meant to be $\sin(x)$? Also, lol at the duplicate...

Comment: @Sharkos Yes, it's used in another language for $\sin$

Comment: @amWhy Since the other question has no answer, should this be closed as duplicate? I noticed that only 1 vote is cast, under "not constructive".

Comment: @Calvin Lin: I think the other question shows a LOT of effort that this post lacks. I posted the duplicate comment long before the answers. I wish those who answered here would have taken the time to answer the question that showed effort, and not this post, if only answering one of the two.

Comment: I didn't know my friend would post the equation either, we' even working together for the same assesment and we both cant solve these problems.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the method you mention, but notice that you can differentiate twice to get
$$\phi''(x)=-\sin x-4\lambda\int_0^\pi dy\ \phi(y)\cos(2x+y),$$
so that
$$\phi''(x)+4\phi(x)=3\sin x.$$
This is easily solved as
$$\phi(x)=\sin x+A\cos(2x)+B\sin(2x)$$
with constants of integration $A$ and $B$. Now plug $\phi$ back in to the integral and solve for $A$ and $B$ in terms of $\lambda$. I get
$$A=\frac{6\pi\lambda^2}{8\lambda^2-9}\qquad{\rm and}\qquad B=\frac{9\pi\lambda}{2(8\lambda^2-9)}.$$

Comment: Not this method but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: expand out $\cos(2x+y)$, and you see that the right side will always be a linear combination of $\sin(x)$, $\cos(2x)$ and $\sin(2x)$.   So the left side...